# Equation of Parabola in terms of angle from vertex located at the origin.

Tags: conic-sections

As we know the equation of ellipse in polar form is $x=a\cos \theta$ and $y=b\sin \theta$.

What is the equation of the parabola $y^2=4ax$ in polar form? Please help me.

Comment: Hint:  $y=r\sin\theta, x=r\cos\theta$

Comment: what is r in case of parabola?

Comment: The polar form of an equation involves $r$ and $\theta$. You have given a common *parametric form* of an ellipse, but it it not the *polar form*. So ... What are you really wanting?

Comment: The parametric form of parametric form of parabola for y2=4ax is x=at^2, y=2at. what is t here?

Comment: I want in parametric form. For a point on the axis of symmetry, I want to find out the nearest point on the perimeter of parabola. Thats I want equation in the form of angle. please help.

Comment: In $x=at^2$, $y=2at$, the $t$ value is simply a *parameter* that guides $x$ and $y$, but it is *not* the angle made by a given point. For what you're trying to do, it doesn't matter. You don't *need* an equation that uses an angle, you just need $x$ and $y$ to be related by a third value (the parameter $t$).

Comment: For a point, say, $(p,0)$ on the axis of symmetry, write an expression for the distance to $(x,y)=(at^2,2at)$. Then find $t$-values that minimize your expression. (Actually, it's more-convenient to minimize the *square* of that expression. The results are the same.) It *doesn't matter* what $t$ represents geometrically. When you find the minimizing $t$-values, you simply substitute them back into $(x,y)=(at^2,2at)$ to get the corresponding points.